# Unable to send required set of tags in response to a web method

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, serialization

I am trying  to call a method from a service hosted at my client IP , One of the method need response to as string .
Method needs Response  as string with following tags :

```
<A>
<User>ABC</User>
<UserDetails>XYZ</User Details>
<UserDetails>ASD</UserDetails>
<UserDetails>QWE</UserDetails>
</A>
```

I have created a custom class to generate the response

```
Class A{
public string User{get;set;}
public string [] UserDetails {get; set}
}
```

I am facing an issue while populating user details every time I convert my object to XML my object Userdetails is modified as

```
<UserDetails>
<string>XYZ</string>
<string>QWE</string>
</UserDetails>
```

Kindly suggest  a solution  how can I get an output  specifically for User Details as

```
<A>
<User>ABC</User>
<UserDetails>XYZ</UserDetails>
<UserDetails>QWE</UserDetails>
</A>
```